# Date format not working

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I have date in string January-01-2014. I wan to set this date to my date picker. I am doing this to set that date but got error like this:

```
Assertion failure in -[_UIDatePickerView _setDate:animated:forced:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/_UIDatePickerView.m:313
2014-01-03 13:17:22.095 GratZeez[1469:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: date'
```

My code is:

```
df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

df.dateStyle=NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
datePicker.date=[df dateFromString:[tempArray objectAtIndex:2]];
```

Comment: Educated guess: Your string is in the wrong format, which means the dateformatter can't create a NSDate. And then datePicker complains because you assigned nil. Put the string and the date to a variable so you can inspect them.

Comment: What u get in NSLog(@"%@", [tempArray objectAtIndex:2]); ?

Comment: date: January-01-2014

Comment: this is not a `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` formatted date. Do `NSLog(@"%@", [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]])` to see how such a formatted string should look like. You have to explicitly specify a dateFormat.

Comment: your datepicker date and your date format are different check

Comment: what is `[tempArray objectAtIndex:2]` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code your app cannot get crashed.

```
df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle=NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd-yyyy"];
datePicker.date=[df dateFromString:[tempArray objectAtIndex:2]];
```

Comment: and how to convert January-01-1980 date to string 01-01-1980

Comment: [df setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
 NSString *str_date=[df stringFromDate:date_Picker.date];

Comment: sorry maul...I ask you wrong....Actually how to convert January-01-1930 string to 01-01-1980...I tried so many format but I cant understand how this formatting works.

Comment: you have to first convert it into date and then take a string from that.

Comment: but this gave me null date

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44395/discussion-between-maul-and-vivek)

Answer (score 0):

check this and change dateformat if causing anything change as your time zone too

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
[formatDate setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss"];
NSTimeZone *zoneTime=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[formate setTimeZone:zoneTime];
NSDate *date = [formate dateFromString:yourDateArray];  
NSLog(@"Output date :%@",date);

[yourDatePicker setDate:date];
```